# Avoid or delay evaluation of things which may not be used

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

How can lazy evaluation be achieved in Python? A couple of simple examples:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     print(x)
...     return x
... 
>>> random.choice((foo('spam'), foo('eggs')))
spam
eggs
'eggs'
```

Above, we didn't really need to evaluate all the items of this tuple, in order to choose one.  And below, the default `foo()` didn't really need to be computed unless the lookup key was actually missing from the dict:

```
>>> d = {1: "one"}
>>> d.get(2, foo("default"))
default
'default'
>>> d.get(1, foo("default"))
default
'one'
```

I'm looking for a Pythonic way to refactor examples like the above to evaluate lazily.

Comment: Yes, what you've described is generally known as lazy evaluation.

Comment: The obvious answer here is simply to apply the ``foo()`` function after making your choice. Also when you are working with iterators, remember to use generators over lists for lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way of doing lazy evaluation in Python is using [generators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/).

```
def foo(x):
    print x
    yield x

random.choice((foo('spam'), foo('eggs'))).next()
```

BTW. Python also allows [generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), so below line will not pre-calculate anything:

```
g = (10**x for x in xrange(100000000))
```

Comment: This will create a bunch of generators and use then only one of them, discarding the rest.  To use lambdas instead is twice as fast because they have way less overhead: `next(random.choice(tuple(foo(q) for q in range(10000000))))` → 21s (without the print of course), `random.choice(tuple(lambda q=q: q+1 for q in range(10000000)))()` → 10s.  So the "ugly" version OP proposed is the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a`partial`(-ly applied function):

```
import random
def foo(x):
    print x
    return x

from functools import partial
print random.choice((partial(foo,'spam'), partial(foo,'eggs')))()
```

When you need a dict with defaults you can use a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(somedefault)
print d[k] # calls somedefault() when the key is missing
```

Python is not a lazy language and there is no special support for laziness. When you want to generate a individual value later, you must wrap it in a function. In addition, `generators` can be used to generate a sequence of values at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you give use a more realistic example, I would do it like this:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     print x
...     return x
...
>>> foo(random.choice(("spam", "eggs")))
spam
'spam'
```

But you could create a helper class like this:

```
class LazyEval(object):
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self):
        return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

random.choice((LazyEval(foo, "spam"), LazyEval(foo, "eggs")))()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to build and return a callable that encapsulates the actions you want to perform on the random selection.

```
def foo(sequence):
    def chooser():
        choice = random.choice(sequence)
        print choice
        return choice
    return chooser

>>> c = foo(['spam', 'eggs', 'ham'])
>>> c()
... ham
>>> 'ham'
```