# Set a value in a dict only if the value is not already set

Tags: python, dictionary, lazy-evaluation

What is the most *pythonic* way to set a value in a `dict` if the value is not already set?

At the moment my code uses if statements:

```
if "timeout" not in connection_settings:
    connection_settings["timeout"] = compute_default_timeout(connection_settings)
```

`dict.get(key,default)` is appropriate for code consuming a dict, not for code that is preparing a dict to be passed to another function.  You can use it to set something but its no prettier imo:

```
connection_settings["timeout"] = connection_settings.get("timeout", \
    compute_default_timeout(connection_settings))
```

would evaluate the compute function even if the dict contained the key; bug.

Defaultdict is when default values are the same.

Of course there are many times you set primative values that don't need computing as defaults, and they can of course use `dict.setdefault`.  But how about the more complex cases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bit of a non-answer, but I would say the most pythonic is the if statement as you have it.  You resisted the urge to one-liner it with `__setitem__` or other methods.  You've avoided possible bugs in the logic due to existing-but-falsey values which might happen when trying to be clever with short-circuiting `and`/`or` hacks.  It's immediately obvious that the compute function isn't used when it wasn't necessary.

It's clear, concise, and readable - *pythonic*.

Comment: I agree there isn't a better way to do it with python today, but I think it has significant drawbacks. In particular, you're repeating the name of the key, so it's ripe for bugs created by misspellings. Because it's a string, most linters won't catch it if you put "timeout" in the if statement, but "timout" in the assignment.  I don't like Ruby for the most part, but one thing I do miss is the ||= operator.   'connection_settings["timeout"] ||= compute_value()'  is concise and readable.

Comment: BTW, ||= is far from perfect. The trap with that operator in Ruby is if the value is in the dictionary, but is falsy (0, empty string etc.)

Comment: Perl has a [really handy //= operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Assignment-Operators) that sets the value only if it is currently undefined.  It can be used with any variable -- not only hashes/dictionaries.

Answer (score 37):

[`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) will precisely "set a value in a dict only if the value is not already set".

You still need to compute the value to pass it in as the parameter:

```
connection_settings.setdefault("timeout", compute_default_timeout(connection_settings))
```

Comment: To future googlers: this is perhaps not the answer that the question asker wanted, but it IS the answer *you* want.

Comment: @CoreDumpError I disagree. Using `if key not in dict: dict[k] = value` (as suggested in the question and the accepted answer) is more readable.

Comment: `dict.setdefault()` is designed to be used when you are effectively *fetching the value for a key*, where you want to ensure the key exists, always. Using it as a setter only goes counter to normal use. Using `if key not in dictionary: dictionary[key] = compute_default_timeout(:..)` is far clearer and straightforward. Moreover, the OP specifically asked for an option that doesn’t compute the new value until needed, **which you can’t do with `dict.setdefault()`.**

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it has already been mentioned by *coredumperror* that this is not the answer the OP wanted. Otherwise, it is a good solution to avoid double lookup (computing hash, etc.) where one suffices.

Comment: @Alexey: looking up an attribute and calling a method has a cost too, though. As hash values for strings are cached, *and* for `setdefault()` you always have to produce the default value *first*, I'd put my money on `if 'timeout' not in connection_settings: connection_settings['timeout'] = compute_default_timeout(connection_settings)` winning out. But now we are micro-optimising, and it'll depend on the rate of key misses versus hits as well.

Comment: *"would evaluate the compute function even if the dict contained the key; bug."*

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is:

```
if key not in dict:
  dict[key] = value
```

Comment: As stated above, [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) does this.

Comment: @slaughter98: that doesn’t make `dict.setdefault()` the correct choice however, because it’s not the only thing `dict.setdefault()` does.

Comment: How is this any different from what was shown in the original question?

Answer (score 5):

Since **Python 3.9** you can use the *merge operator* `|` to merge two dictionaries. The dict on the right takes precedence:

```py
d = { key: value } | d
```

Note: this creates a new dictionary with the updated values.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need `dict.setdefault`:

Create a new dictionary and set a value:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('timeout', 120)
120
>>> d
{'timeout': 120}
```

If a value already set, `dict.setdefault` won't override it:

```
>>> d['port']=8080
>>> d.setdefault('port', 8888)
8080
>>> d
{'port': 8080, 'timeout': 120}
```

Comment: "would evaluate the compute function even if the dict contained the key; bug"

Comment: That is not a bug: `compute_default_timeout()` must be called before calling `dict.get()`--That might not be what the OP wants, but that's the correct behavior.

Comment: The quote is from the question, so it is clear that the behaviour is equivalent to something which the OP already considers a bug  (I wouldn't call it a bug myself, but it's still unnecessary and undesirable in this case)

Comment: My point was it's obviously not useful to the OP, because they have already dismissed an equivalent alternative for that reason..  

By the way, I asked a question once about this behaviour already and whether it could be made "lazy" ...  :)   http://stackoverflow.com/q/9802981/674039

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following to modify kwargs to non-default values and pass to another function:

```
def f( **non_default_kwargs ):

    kwargs = {
        'a':1,
        'b':2,
    }
    kwargs.update( non_default_kwargs )

    f2( **kwargs )
```

This has the merits that

- you don't have to type the keys twice
- all is done in a single function

Comment: I think you are assuming too much about the use-case.  The OP might not have (or even want) a pre-existing and pre-computed collection of sensible defaults.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Rotareti makes me wonder if for older version of Python then 3.9, we can do:

```
>>> dict_a = {'a': 1 }
>>> dict_a = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, **dict_a}
>>> dict_a

{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

(Well, it works for sure on Python3.7, but is this Pythonesque enough?)

Answer (score -1):

I found it convenient and obvious to exploit the return of the dict `.get()` method being `None` (Falsy), along with `or` to put off evaluation of an expensive network request if the key was not present.

```
d = dict()

def fetch_and_set(d, key):
    d[key] = ("expensive operation to fetch key")
    if not d[key]:
        raise Exception("could not get value")
    return d[key]

...

value = d.get(key) or fetch_and_set(d, key)
```

---

In my case specifically, I was building a *new* dictionary from a cache then later updating the cache after expediting the `fn()` call.

Here's a simplified view of my use

```
j = load(database)  # dict
d = dict()

# see if desired keys are in the cache, else fetch
for key in keys:
    d[key] = j.get(key) or fetch(key, network_token)

fn(d)  # use d for something useful

j.update(d)  # update database with new values (if any)
```