# Python update a key in dict if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to insert a key-value pair into dict if key not in dict.keys().
Basically I could do it with:

```
if key not in d.keys():
    d[key] = value
```

But is there a better way? Or what's the pythonic solution to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a value in a dict only if the value is not already set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965146/set-a-value-in-a-dict-only-if-the-value-is-not-already-set)

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You do not need to call `d.keys()`, so

```
if key not in d:
    d[key] = value
```

is enough. There is no clearer, more readable method.

You could update again with `dict.get()`, which would return an existing value if the key is already present:

```
d[key] = d.get(key, value)
```

but I strongly recommend against this; this is code golfing, hindering maintenance and readability.

Comment: Do I need to synchronize this if I have multiple threads using the code?

Comment: @ed22 yes, because it consists of multiple bytecode instructions, in between which threads can switch.

Comment: Is this idea practical?
try:
    dict[key] += 1
except KeyError:
    dict[key] = 1

Comment: @hatahetahmad: sure, but that's 4 lines, not 2.

Comment: I am considering the complexity, the expression "for k in keys run in O(k)", in the other hand "try except needs only O(1)". Please correct me if I am wrong; Thank you.

Comment: @hatahetahmad: loops and exception handling should not be compared on the grounds of their time complexity, that just makes no sense. Compare [Asking for Forgiveness vs. Asking for Permission](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing/175663#175663) instead, and the answer then depends on *how often will you need to ask*.

Comment: Suppose you are filling in a `kwargs` object with default keyword values. Then the `if x in kwargs` grammar becomes obtuse, unchangeable (the keystrokes to modify are enormous, automatic modification per line with macros or patterns is difficult, etc.), and painful (on the hands) when wrapping a complex library function with a specific kwarg default-argument override. It may be easier to read for beginners, but I would also argue it is harder to read for novices and experts.

Comment: @Chris: There are much better ways of providing default values for a set of keys in a dictionary than this. Use `kwargs = {"key1": "default1", "key2": "default2", ...} | kwargs` for that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ha , I do. It is particularly annoying how mypy yells at me every time, but this is the way I do it as well.

Comment: @hatahetahmad where did you even see any `for k in keys` happening?

Answer (score 184):

Use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
>>> d = {'key1': 'one'}
>>> d.setdefault('key1', 'some-unused-value')
'one'
>>> d    # d has not changed because the key already existed
{'key1': 'one'}
>>> d.setdefault('key2', 'two')
'two'
>>> d
{'key1': 'one', 'key2': 'two'}
```

Comment: `dict.setdefault()` should really only be used when trying to access the value too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: why does that matter? The name `setdefault()` clearly describes what is happening - that it also returns a value is not that important, and a little quirky IMO. Could you provide a quick explanation, or a link to one, as to why this is not desirable?

Comment: You'd use it in an expression that expects a value to exist, like in a grouping loop: `for obj in iterable: d.setdefault(key_for_obj(obj), []).append(obj)`. There is nothing quirky about the value being returned, *that's the whole point of the method*.

Comment: Also, it obscures what you are trying to do, which is to set a key only if it is not already present. Readability counts, just use a `if key not in d:` test.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the explanation. Having read the docstring, `setdefault()` does seem to be geared to what you have said. Using a `defaultdict(list)` would result in more readable code than your example... so perhaps there is no use for it unless one must work with standard dictionaries. Overall, `if key not in d` is clearer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd say you're just wrong here. For “an expression that expects a value to exist”, but you don't want to update the dict, you would simply use `get` with a default value. The whole point of `setdefault` is that it does perform the update – which then also naturally provides an lvalue for the element in question, but whether or not you immediately use that is up to you.

Answer (score 58):

Since **Python 3.9** you can use the *merge operator* `|` to merge two dictionaries. The dict on the right takes precedence:

```py
new_dict = old_dict | { key: val }
```

For example:

```py
new_dict = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 } | { 'b': 42 }

print(new_dict) # {'a': 1, 'b': 42}
```

Note: this creates a new dictionary with the updated values.

Comment: While this is interesting, I do not think it is more readable than the accepted answer

Comment: For me, it's just nice to know there's a way to merge two dicts now

Comment: There is a challenge with this merge. If the keys are the same, the merge will ignore the value. If that's the intent, then it works.

Comment: @JoeFerndz The dict on the right takes precedence and won't ignore the value. I updated the example to make this more clear.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Can have a dict with default values and the only update the ones present in the new dict.

Comment: The question is asking how to "update a key in dict *if it doesn't exist*" so the desired output would be for the dict to stay the same `{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }` because `'b' in old_dict` already. So you'd have to put the other dictionary first `{ key: val } | old_dict`.

Comment: Merging two dicts, why not ```new_dict = {**one_dict, **another-dict}``` ? (sincere question)

Comment: For reference: the paragraph "d | other" on the page https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: @Ideogram this is a good enough question that it was directly addressed in [PEP 584](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/)!

Comment: @ArthurMorris, to quote the PEP584: "Dict unpacking looks ugly and is not easily discoverable. Few people would be able to guess what it means the first time they see it, or think of it as the “obvious way” to merge two dicts." Their words, not mine :)

Comment: As noted by @user3064538, the answer here is wrong if the right dict takes precedence. Rather you should reverse the order in the merge.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use this solution in only one line of code:

```
dict[dict_key] = dict.get(dict_key,value)
```

The second argument of `dict.get` is the value you want to assign to the key in case the key does not exist. Since this evaluates before the assignment to `dict[dict_key] =` , we can be sure that they key will exist when we try to access it.

Answer (score 15):

With the following you can insert multiple values and also have default values but you're creating a new dictionary.

```py
d = {**{ key: value }, **default_values}
```

I've tested it with the most voted answer and on average this is faster as it can be seen in the following example, .

[image: Speed test comparing a for loop based method with a dict comprehension with unpack operator]
Speed test comparing a for loop based method with a dict comprehension with unpack operator method.

if no copy (`d = default_vals.copy()`) is made on the first case then the most voted answer would be faster once we reach orders of magnitude of `10**5` and greater. Memory footprint of both methods are the same.

Comment: Then why suggest it in the first place

Comment: thank you so much. But it seems should be `{**default_values, **{ key: value }}`