# Avoid using if statements for checking keys in dict

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, design-patterns

I am trying to map some values from data to a template.
I want to fill in the values (with some manipulations) in the template only if they are already present in it.
My template has hundreds of keys and my goal is to avoid the if statement before each manipulation and assignment.

The point of the if statements is to defer evaluation of the manipulations I am performing as they may be expensive to perform. Any solutions should take this into account.

```
data = {
    'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3,
    'd':4,
    'e':5
}

template1 = {
    'p':'Nan',
    'q':'Nan',
    'r':'Nan'
}

template2 = {
    'p':'Nan',
    's':'Nan',
    't':'Nan'
}

def func(template,data):
    if 'p' in template.keys():
        template['p'] = data['a']
    if 'q' in template.keys():
        template['q'] = data['b'][:2] + 'some manipulation'
    if 'r' in template.keys():
        template['r'] = data['c']
    if 's' in template.keys():
        template['s'] = data['d'] + 'some mainpulation'
    if 't' in template.keys():
        template['t'] = data['e']
```

I know I am missing something basic, my actual code and requirements are pretty complex and I tried to simplify them and bring them down to this simple structure.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965146/set-a-value-in-a-dict-only-if-the-value-is-not-already-set

Comment: Hi @Li, but this method would not account for the manipulations I am performing with the data values before the assignment

Comment: You could wrap it inside a function `def set_if_exists(dct, key, value): if key in dct: dct[key] = value` and then use it like `set_if_exists(template, 'p', data['a'])`. This doesn't actually eliminate the conditionals but hides them behind a wrapper. The other option would be to subclass `dict` and give it a method that fits your needs but that doesn't seem optimal either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your manipulations can be expressed as a simple lambda, you could encapsulate the condition/assigment in a function to reduce the code clutter:

```
def func(template,data):
    def apply(k,action):
        if k in template: template[k] = action()
    apply('p',lambda: data['a'])
    apply('q',lambda: data['b'][:2] + 'some manipulation')
    apply('r',lambda: data['c'])
    apply('s',lambda: data['d'] + 'some mainpulation')
    apply('t',lambda: data['e'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Alain, looks like this is a very comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could also store manipulations directly in your data dict using lambda functions, then check if any retrieved value from the data dict is callable() when using this dict to update the template.  Assuming your can't modify the keys in the data dict, then this approach could still work with the template_dict mapping approach suggested by Jlove.

```
data = {
    'p': 1,
    'q': 2,
    'r': 3,
    's': 4,
    't': 5,
    'u': lambda x: x * 2
}

template1 = {
    'p':'Nan',
    'q':'Nan',
    'r':'Nan',
    'u': 2
}


def func(template, data):
    for key in template:
        if callable(data[key]):
           template[key] = data[key](template[key])
        else:
            template[key] = data[key]

#driver
func(template1, data)

for k in template1.items():
    print(k)
```

--- expanded solution based on comments ---

basically the same as the above, but shows how to use a mapping dict to direct how the data dict and an actions dict can be combined to modify the template dict.  Also shows how to map keys to functions using a dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def qManipulation(x):
    return x * 10

def sManipulation(x):
    return x * 3

data = {
'a':1,
'b':2,
'c':3,
'd':4,
'e':5
}

actions = {
'q': qManipulation,
's': sManipulation,
'u': lambda x: x * 7
}

tempToDataMap = defaultdict(lambda: None, {
'p': 'a',
'q': 'b',
'r': 'c',
's': 'd',
't': 'e'
})

template1 = {
'p':'Nan',
'q':'Nan',
'r':'Nan',
'u': 2
}

def func(template, data):
    for key, val in template.items():
        dataKey = tempToDataMap[key]
    
        # check if the template key corrosponds to a data dict key
        if dataKey is not None:

            # if key mapping from template to data is actually in data dict, use data value in template
            if dataKey in data:
                template[key] = data[dataKey]

            # if the template key is registered to an action in action dict, run action
            if key in actions:
                template[key] = actions[key](data[dataKey])
        

        # use this if you have a manipulation on a template field that is not populated by data.
        # this isn't present in the example, but could be handy if the template ever has default values other that Nan
        elif key in actions:
            template[key] = actions[key](template[key])


func(template1, data)

for k in template1.items():
    print(k)
```

Comment: The "pretty complex" aspect of the data manipulation might be too difficult to squeeze in a Python lambda :)

Comment: Good point, but if that is the case, the same approach could still be used by defining the complex logic in another function, then assigning the function in place of the lambda.  If the complex logic is in function example(x) then the key value pair "u": lambda x: x becomes "u": example.  -- edited original comment as better syntax was available.

Comment: data and the templates are my input dicts (tables) I cannot modify them.

Comment: If thats the case, then you still need a mapping dict that associates your template keys to your data keys.  You can then have an additional "actions" dict that stores your manipulations, or references to functions that contain your manipulations. You then encapsulate the relationship between the actions dict, data dict, and template in what is now your func() function.  This has the effect of offloading your sequence of if statements to a dict organization.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a great idea but you could subclass `dict` and override `__setitem__`.

```
class GuardDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, callable_value):
        if key in self:
            super().__setitem__(key, callable_value())
    # we need a method to transform back to a dict
    def to_dict(self):
        return dict(self)


data = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': '2',
    'c': 3,
    'd': '4',
    'e': 5
}

template1 = {
    'p':'Nan',
    'q':'Nan',
    'r':'Nan'
}

template2 = {
    'p':'Nan',
    's':'Nan',
    't':'Nan'
}

def func(template,data):
    # create a GuardDict from the dict
    # this will utilize __setitem__ and only actually set keys
    # that already exist in the original dict
    template = GuardDict(template)
    template['p'] = lambda: data['a']
    template['q'] = lambda: data['b'] + 'some manipulation'
    template['r'] = lambda: data['c']
    template['s'] = lambda: data['d'] + 'some mainpulation'
    template['t'] = lambda: data['e']
    # set back to a dict
    return template.to_dict()

template1 = func(template1, data)
template2 = func(template2, data)
print(template1)
print(template2)
```

I should probably note if there are other users of your code they will probably hate you for this.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer @Axe319. This is a good alternative but not what I'm looking for. I am looking to avoid the computation time for the manipulation being performed (like how an if statement would do). I am assuming this step would ignore setting the value for the key. But would it still compute the right-hand side of the equation? Also, you're welcome to reframe the question if its not clear, I'm quite new at this.

Comment: I modified it. It's still horrific but an option. ;)

Answer (score 0):

a dynamically functional approach might relieve you from all the ifs and elses, but might complicate the overall program structure.

```py
data = {
    'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3,
    'd':4,
    'e':5
}

template1 = {
    'p': 'Nan',
    'q': 'Nan',
    'r': 'Nan'
}

template2 = {
    'p': 'Nan',
    's': 'Nan',
    't': 'Nan'
}

# first, define your complex logic in functions, accounting for every possible template key


def p_logic(data, x):
    return data[x]


def q_logic(data, x):
    return data[x][:2] + 'some manipulation'

# Then build a dict of every possible template key, the associated value and reference to one of the
# functions defined above


logic = {
    'p': {
        'value': 'a',
        'logic': p_logic
    },
    'q': {
        'value': 'b',
        'logic': q_logic
    },
}


def func(template, data):
    # for every key in a template, lookup that key in our logic dict
    # grab the value from the data
    # and apply the complex logic that has been defined for this template value 
    for item in template:  # template.keys() is not necessary!
        template[item] = logic[item]['logic'](data, logic[item]['value'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer MKX, but this would complicate the program structure unnecessarily. I think this would be better off with using if statements

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I could think to do here would be to have some sort of dict and run your template through a for loop instead. Such as:

```
template_dict = {'p': 'a', 'q': 'b', 'r': 'c', 's': 'd', 't': 'e'}

def func(template, data):
    for key, value in template_dict.items():
        if key in template.keys():
            template[key] = data[value]
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure how you might be able to avoid all those conditionals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jlove, but this method would not account for the manipulations I am performing with the data values before the assignment

Comment: Yeah, that's tough. If anything, you could go this route and then pick out special cases where you need further manipulation. Might boil down a few hundred conditionals to a more manageable number.