# Preventing a dict with Classes as values from instantiating unless needed?

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that looks roughly like this:

```
input_data = {...}
my_list = [
    {"a": Class1(input_data)},
    {"b": Class2(input_data)},
    {"c": Class3(input_data)}
]
```

I want to be able to maintain a list like the one above but without all of the classes being instantiated until I need them. Sometimes I'll need to go through all of them, however most times I'll just need to access one of them. As it is now, they all get instantiated and make my runtime longer even if I'm only using one of dicts in the list.

How can I prevent the classes from being instantiated until I need them?

Comment: related:  [Avoid or delay evaluation of things which may not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9802981/674039)

Comment: What's the point of having a list of dicts where each dict only has a single key? This looks like you'd do yourself a favor if you got rid of either the list or the dicts. Is there a reason why you can't use a structure like `{'a': Class1(input_data), 'b': Class2(input_data), 'c': Class3(input_data)}`?

Comment: Wait, are you sure you want a list of single-time dictionarties, not a multi-item dictionary?

Comment: How exactly do you create the list? The code in your question cannot possible be anything like your real code. Surely you don't define separate classes for each item - and do you *really* pass the same input data to every one of them? Please show a much more realistic example.

Comment: @DyZ I need it in a list because the existing code is accessing by index still and I can't touch that legacy code yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just put the class and its input in a tuple:

```
input_data = {...}
my_list = [
    {"a": (Class1, input_data)},
    {"b": (Class2, input_data)},
    {"c": (Class3, input_data)}
]
```

Then when I want to instantiate:

```
tup = my_list[0]["a"]
instantiated_class = tup[0](tup[1])
```

Comment: Awesome! This works with minimal modifications to the existing code. Ideally, I wouldn't have this setup with multiple classes with a list of dicts, but I'm dealing with a lot of legacy code that I simply don't have the time to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you are looking for a dictionary with multiple items, not a list of single-item dictionaries.

You can initialize the dictionary with class constructors rather than class objects and create objects later:

```
input_data = {...}
my_dict = {
    "a": Class1,
    "b": Class2,
    "c": Class3
}

def get_item(d, key, data = input_data):
    if isinstance(d[key], type): 
        d[key] = d[key](data)
    return d[key]
```

Later:

```
get_item(my_dict, "a") # Returns a Class1 instance
```

Perhaps you can even derive a new "smart" dictionary from `dict` and redefine its `__getitem__` to instantiate objects when they are accessed for the first time.

Comment: I didn't know I could just list the constructors without having to initialize, so thanks for the info. I need it in a list because the legacy code that accesses it was doing so by index (when it was just a list of the current keys) and I can't change that code yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn them into functions that return the desired object and which you only evaluate as needed.

```
my_list = [
    {"a": lambda: Class1(input_data)},
    {"b": lambda: Class2(input_data)},
    {"c": lambda: Class3(input_data)}
]

c1 = my_list[0]["a"]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `dict` along the lines (bare minimum, you may have to override more methods for a smooth experience):

```
>>> class delayed_dict(dict):
...     def __init__(self, backstore):
...         super().__init__()
...         self._backstore=backstore
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         if not key in self:
...             fun, *args = self._backstore[key]
...             self[key] = fun(*args)
...         return super().__getitem__(key)
```

Applied to your example:

```
>>> input_data = (1, 2, 3)
>>> Class1 = list
>>> Class2 = tuple
>>> Class3 = dict.fromkeys
>>> 
>>> my_list = [
...     {"a": (Class1, input_data)},
...     {"b": (Class2, input_data)},
...     {"c": (Class3, input_data)}
... ]
>>> 
>>> lazy = list(map(delayed_dict, my_list))
>>> 
>>> lazy
[{}, {}, {}]
>>> 
>>> x = lazy[1]['b']
>>> x is lazy[1]['b']
True
>>> x
(1, 2, 3)
>>> lazy
[{}, {'b': (1, 2, 3)}, {}]
```

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you need a generator. A generator creates each element as needed when you're iterating over it (the downside is, you can't iterate over the generator again; once you've "used" an element, it's gone). `range` in Python is a (somewhat special) example of a generator. I'm not sure how you're going to pull out the single/few items you need from your list, though - will you just need the first few, or do you access them by index? Here's a generator example you could use if you're just going to use the first items from your list:

```
class C1:
    def __init__(*args):
        print("C1 init")

class C2:
    def __init__(*args):
        print("C2 init")

class C3:
    def __init__(*args):
        print("C3 init")

classes = [C1, C2, C3]
keys = 'abc'
data = [3, 5]
gen = ({keys[i]: classes[i](*data)} for i in range(len(keys)))

# each time you want an element out:
new_dict = next(gen)
```

If you want to be able to get the items out by index instead, other answers will probably work better.